# unable to confirm transaction

Tags: confirmation

Hi just today I started to get this error when trying to do anything on devnet:

Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds

This includes just doing:

solana airdrop 1

on the terminal.

Some things work, e.g. solana balance shows a sensible value, but I can't seem to do anything with transactions.  The airdrop doesn't go through, it just sits there for a while and then I get that error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of your posting, there are some issues with `devnet` that are prevent transactions from going through. If you are using `devnet` and running into these issues, you may just have to wait until they are resolved.

You can try running the same code using the local host validator or on `testnet` to make sure the problem is not with your code, and is in fact with the current devnet troubles.

Comment: thanks, i guess https://status.solana.com/ is the place to check for that in the future?

Comment: That is a great place to get the status, but it may not give the full picture (depending on what is causing network troubles). You can also check the Solana discord and twitter accounts for more information.